# How to pass data from ASP.NET to a javascript-created component?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

I've been tasked with creating a tree-style list of data, something like this:

http://paulneale.com/tutorials/dotNet/treeView/treeView02.png

The only information I've been given is that it must be populated dynamically: 'value', 'text' pairs are passed to the webpage at run-time. The other piece of information is that it must be coded in Javascript/jQuery, as there cannot be any postbacks from ASP.NET.

These 'value', 'text' pairs are to be passed from ASP.NET.

Could anyone kindly explain how this may be done?

Unfortunately I've been given vague requirements, and trying to piece the puzzle together.

Comment: Hmmm...sounds like your homework, you want us to explain how to do your homework?

Answer (score 0):

Look at one of the free jQuery Tree View plug-ins such as [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/).  You'll want to populate the tree using AJAX and a server-side web service.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsFiddle created by @Amin Eshaq. It creates a tree view using jQuery, without any additional plugins.

http://jsfiddle.net/8JjD2/1/